# Modern Opengl GLSL Shader Class

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

I've finally written my own `Shader` class. It's a basic implementation based on a tutorial, and it works perfectly. Any suggestions on how to improve, or correct my code are welcome!

**Shader.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "LogManager.h"
#include "bindable.h"
#include "disposable.h"

#define NUM_SHADER_TYPES 4

class Shader : public Bindable, public Disposable
{
public:
    Shader();
    virtual ~Shader();

    void loadFromText(GLenum type, const std::string& src);
    void loadFromFile(GLenum type, const char* fileName);
    void loadFromPreCompiledText(GLenum type, const std::string& src){}
    void loadFromPreCompiledFile(GLenum type, const char* fileName){}
    void CreateAndLink();
    void RegisterAttribute(const char* attrib);
    void RegisterUniform(const char* uniform);
    GLuint GetProgramID() const;
    ///accesses elements : shaders/uniforms;
    GLuint GetAttribLocation(const char* attrib);
    GLuint operator[](const char* attrib);
    GLuint GetUniformLocation(const char* unif);
    GLuint operator()(const char* unif);

    virtual void Bind() const;
    virtual void UnBind() const;
    virtual void Dispose();

private:
    enum ShaderType { VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER, GEOMETRY_SHADER, PIXEL_SHADER};
    GLuint _program ;
    int _numShaders;
    GLuint _shaders[4]; /// VERTEX, FRAGMENT, GEOMETRY AND PIXEL_SHADERS !
    std::map<std::string, GLuint> _attribList;
    std::map<std::string, GLuint> _unifLocationList;
};
```

**Shader.cpp**

```
#include "Shader.h"
#include "LogManager.h"
#include "fstream"

Shader::Shader()
    :_program(0), _numShaders(0)
{
    _shaders[VERTEX_SHADER] = 0;
    _shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER] = 0;
    _shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER] = 0;
    _shaders[PIXEL_SHADER] = 0;
    _attribList.clear();
    _unifLocationList.clear();
}

Shader::~Shader(){
    _attribList.clear();
    _unifLocationList.clear();
}

void Shader::loadFromText(GLenum type, const std::string& text){
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* cstr = text.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &cstr, nullptr);

    ///compile + check shader load status
    GLint status;
    glCompileShader(shader);
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(status == GL_FALSE){
        GLint infoLogSize;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogSize);
        GLchar *infoLog = new GLchar[infoLogSize];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLogSize, nullptr, infoLog);
        LOG_ERROR("Shader", infoLog);
        delete [] infoLog;
    }
    _shaders[_numShaders++]=shader;
}

void Shader::CreateAndLink(){
    _program = glCreateProgram();
    if(_shaders[VERTEX_SHADER] != 0)
        glAttachShader(_program, _shaders[VERTEX_SHADER]);
    if(_shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER] != 0)
        glAttachShader(_program, _shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER]);
    if(_shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER] != 0)
        glAttachShader(_program, _shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER]);
    if(_shaders[PIXEL_SHADER] != 0)
        glAttachShader(_program, _shaders[PIXEL_SHADER]);

    ///link + check
    GLint status;
    glLinkProgram(_program);
    glGetProgramiv(_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if(status == GL_FALSE){
        GLint infoLogSize;
        glGetProgramiv(_program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogSize);
        GLchar *infoLog = new GLchar[infoLogSize];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_program, infoLogSize, nullptr, infoLog);
        delete [] infoLog;
    }

    glDetachShader(_program, _shaders[VERTEX_SHADER]);
    glDetachShader(_program, _shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER]);
    glDetachShader(_program, _shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER]);
    glDetachShader(_program, _shaders[PIXEL_SHADER]);

    glDeleteShader(_shaders[VERTEX_SHADER]);
    glDeleteShader(_shaders[FRAGMENT_SHADER]);
    glDeleteShader(_shaders[GEOMETRY_SHADER]);
    glDeleteShader(_shaders[PIXEL_SHADER]);
}

void Shader::Bind() const{
    glUseProgram(_program);
}

void Shader::UnBind() const{
    glUseProgram(0);
}

void Shader::RegisterAttribute(const char* attrib){
    _attribList[attrib] = glGetAttribLocation(_program, attrib);
}

void Shader::RegisterUniform(const char* unif){
    _unifLocationList[unif] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, unif);
}

GLuint Shader::GetAttribLocation(const char* attrib){
    return _attribList[attrib];
}
GLuint Shader::operator[](const char* attrib){
    return _attribList[attrib];
}

GLuint Shader::GetUniformLocation(const char* unif){
    return _unifLocationList[unif];
}
GLuint Shader::operator()(const char* unif){
    return _unifLocationList[unif];
}

GLuint Shader::GetProgramID() const{ return _program; }

void Shader::loadFromFile(GLenum which, const char* fileName){
    std::ifstream fparser;
    fparser.open(fileName, std::ios_base::in);
    if(fparser){
        ///read + load
        std::string buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fparser), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
        loadFromText(which, buffer);
    }
    else{
        LOG_ERROR_INFO("Shader", "Invalid fileName path", fileName);
    }
}

void Shader::Dispose(){
    glDeleteProgram(_program);
    _program = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Comments on design:

Inheriting from `Bindable` and `Disposable` is an interesting approach, though I don't think I'd do it myself. It will add more complexity to your code and more header/source files to maintain. You should consider that when making the decision. There aren't that many practical benefits that I can think of, besides the interface template for new classes to follow. In my opinion, a more useful base class would be a `RenderResource` that combines all the common properties and behavior of renderer (OpenGL) resources. Such base class could indeed make your implementation cleaner and facilitate storage of resource objects, like shaders and textures, to name a few.

Going into more specific details, I didn't like these guys:

> ```
> GLuint operator[](const char* attrib);
> GLuint operator()(const char* unif);
> ```

From the parameter names I can tell that the first one is a wrapper to `GetAttribLocation()` and the second to `GetUniformLocation()`. But how about the calling code? It will be impossible for an outsider to distinguish something like the following:

```
GLuint normal = shader["normal_vector"];
// bunch of GL calls
// ...

GLuint color = shader("diffuse_color");
// bunch of GL calls
// ...

// Which of the above was operating on a uniform var and which on a vertex attrib?
```

Unless one takes the trouble to further read down the code and figure out if the integer handle refers to a *uniform variable* or a *vertex attribute*, based on the GL calls, it is impossible to quickly tell the difference.

My first advice here would be to just throw away both operator overloads. Second advice is to define two small value classes: `ShaderUniform` and `VertexAttribute`, to provide type safety and context. A `GLuint` is used to describe **any** OpenGL resource (unfortunate, but understandable in a plain C API).

```
class ShaderUniform
{
public:
    // Not much to see here, perhaps just a
    // `getGLHandle()` to access the underlaying `GLuint`.
    // The sole purpose of this class is to provide type
    // information to differentiate from, say a `VertexAttribute`.
    // Also, keep it simple to that it can still be used as a
    // value type.
private:
    GLuint glHandle;
    // Whatever other auxiliar data you might need.
};

// Then in the Shader class, `GetUniformLocation()` would return its 
// unique type, rather then the opaque `GLuint`:
//
ShaderUniform GetUniformLocation() const { ... }
```

#### Other details in your current implementation:

- Targeting C++11, methods implemented from a base class can now be annotated with the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier. This new keyword will improve compiler diagnostics if you accidentally overload and shadow a base class method. It might also aid de-virtualization optimizations done by the compiler. Also note that you don't need to specify `virtual` again in the child class, unless that class will itself be further inherited and extended.

  ```
  void Bind() const override;
  void UnBind() const override;
  void Dispose() override;
  ```
- You have mixed method naming conventions. E.g.: `loadFromText()` and `CreateAndLink()`. It would be nicer to be consistent. `camelCase` is very commonly used in C++ code for anything that can have its memory address taken. This includes variables and functions/methods. While `PascalCase` is very often applied to type names (I.e.: classes, structs, enums).
- I see that both the `loadFromPreCompiled*()` methods are currently not implemented. This is fine but it would be a smart idea to let the user know that, in case one of the methods is called while still not implemented. A `NotImplementedError` exception would be a good idea. If not, at least an [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert).
- Take a look at [`enum class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) (scoped enumerations, C++11). The C++ community is in general abandoning the older C-style enum.
- No apparent reason for having `NUM_SHADER_TYPES` as a global constant. And certainly no reason whatsoever for using a `#define`. [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) is the C++11 way of declaring compile-time constants. If your compiler doesn't happen to support it yet, then `const` will suffice.
- You have two conflicting definitions in you `ShaderType` enum: `FRAGMENT_SHADER` and `PIXEL_SHADER`. This is also reflecting in all of your code. A *Fragment Shader* is the same thing as a *Pixel Shader*. The diference is that the latter term is used by Microsoft's D3D, while the former is the term used by OpenGL. Both name the same pipeline stage. The term used by OpenGL is more semantically correct, IMHO, since a *fragment* processed by the shader doesn't necessarily becomes a *pixel* on the screen. Read [this discussion](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/388566-pixel-shader-vs-fragment-shader/) for more.

  Anyways, you have these several calls referring to both types when they are actually just one. So you have some cleanup there to consolidate both.
- Unneeded map clearing in the destructor:

  > ```
  > Shader::~Shader(){
  >     _attribList.clear();
  >     _unifLocationList.clear();
  > }
  > ```

  A `std::map` is an automatic container. It will be cleared without your intervention when the parent object gets destroyed. This is useless at best, repeated work in the worse case.

  What I **would** be calling in the destructor though, is the `Dispose()` method. If users of `Shader` forget to call it manually, you run the risk of leaking a shader program object!

Comment: 1) Thanks :°) By the way, I have doubts now if my shader class  disposes its shaders correctly... Do I need to worry ?

Comment: 2) Yes, I agree that inheriting from Bindable and Disposable is a "werid" approach; but I'm trying to design a library, so I want the user to know that he **must** dispose the shader ! (otherwise, the destructor takes care of it...)

Comment: 3) After playing around a bit with my class, I noticed a problem : calling LoadFromFile twice with the same GLSL file type leads to problems ! Also, calling it more then 4 times leads to **BIG** problems : Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: @MattMatt, It will leak the shader program object if no one calls `Dispose()`. I think this is an unnecessary burden on the user when you can just call it inside the destructor of `Shader`.

Comment: OK ! I saw that you talked about spliting things into 2 structs : ShaderUniform, and VertexAttribute : can you give me an idea of its implementation

Comment: @MattMatt, "BIG problems" on `loadFromFile`? That's quite vague. I didn't spot anything wrong with the function, but I think it would be better for you to then formulate a more specific StackOverflow question about this instead.

Comment: Thanks ! For Big problems, I meant that nothing is rendered ! Actually, the problem is that the program does not check in the LoadFromText method, if the _shaders array is out of bounds ! The other problem is the following : what if I call my LoadFromText method with, let's say, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER **twice** ?

Comment: @MattMatt, added some pseudo-code, hope it is understandable enough. If you try to attach two shaders of the same type to one program, the last one will simply override the previous. No erros should be generated from the GL side. It is up to you to catch this kind of mistakes. Not sure if I get the  bounds thing, but in C++ arrays **are not** bounds checked by the runtime. Again, you have to capture that sort or errors yourself.

Comment: @MattMatt, Oh, I think I see where your bug is: `_shaders[_numShaders++]=shader;` in `loadFromText`. If you keep calling that function, `_numShaders` will just go beyond the size of the array and access memory outside your addressing space. A simple `if` check to return with an error when `_numShaders == 4` should fix your "big problems".